Config routing with a constant string with a param in angular
I want to config routing like this : hotel-123, hotel-456,... with 'hotel' is a constant string and 123, 456 is param 'code'.
This is my app.routes.ts :
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
    
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'hotel-:code',
        loadComponent: () => import('../pages/hotel/hotel.component').then(m => m.HotelComponent)
    }
];

..but it's not work. I got error 'Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'hotel-123'' when trying access this path.
I spent hours for searching this but there aren't any clue. Is this possilble in Angular ? Do you have any solution for this ?
P/s : I use Angular 17.3.6
Thanks for reading !

This question is similar to: Angular routing for prefix with route parameter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://v17.angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

As @JSON Derulo 's suggest, i found the solution after many tries.
In app.routes.ts :
import { Routes, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        matcher : (url) => {
            if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^hotel-[\w-]+$/gm)) {
                return {
                    consumed: url,
                    posParams: {
                        code: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substring(6), {}) // with my example '/hotel-123', code value will be '123'
                    }
                };
            }
            
            return null;
        },
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/hotel/hotel.component').then(c => c.HotelComponent)
    },
];

In hotel.component.ts :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-hotel',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './hotel.component.html',
  styleUrl: './hotel.component.scss'
})
export class HotelComponent {

  code : string;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe(paramsMap => {
      this.code = paramsMap.get('code') ?? '';

      // do something ...
    })
  }
}

Also, @Eliseo's comment is helpful too !
Angular Matcher document

The params need to be separated by / only, so you need to restructure your routing to.
It's possible using canMatch but it's an ugly solution so I'm recommending the best and easiest solution.
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'hotel/:code',
        loadComponent: () => import('../pages/hotel/hotel.component').then(m => m.HotelComponent)
    }
];


While that is correct, it somewhat irrelevant. He wants the route to be /[static string]-[dynamic string], your route configuration would be /[static string]-/[dynamic string]

@tony yes I understand but its not possible is my point, I have read the question

In app.module.ts:
You can configure the router for HotelComponent like this:
 {
    path: ':code',
    loadComponent: () => import('../pages/hotel/hotel.component').then(m => m.HotelComponent)
}

In the HTML, you can set the routerLink dynamically like this:
<mat-card [routerLink]="['hotel-' + '1']">
  <mat-card-title>Go to Menu1</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
<mat-card [routerLink]="['hotel-' + '2']">
  <mat-card-title>Go to Menu2</mat-card-title>
</mat-card>

The hotel- part is a static string, and you can concatenate the dynamic part, such as the code 1 or 2, from the TypeScript file. Then, bind it in the HTML and pass it to the routerLink.

this makes ALL routes fall in this case

@Eliseo Can you please explain briefly the issue that you are facing  by using the given code?

@Viji_Pykara this will match all routes, not only routes is started with static string 'hotel', but also '/room', '/spa' or anything like '/abcxyz',...
